# Variable width div (with minium width) in between two fixed width divs

Tags: css, html, variable-width

I'm trying to place three divs side by side.

- The first div has a fixed width and needs to be against the left side of the screen (ie: `float:left;`).
- The next div also has a fixed width and needs to be against the right side of the screen (ie: `float:right;`).
- And the last div needs to fill the space in between them and adjust based on the width of the browser window.

When a certain minimum width is reached for this last div in the middle I need it to stop getting smaller and have scroll bars appear in the browser.

Is this possible to achieve?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sfxX8/). basically, there are 3 divs, 2 of them which placed on the side are `fixed width absolute position` div while the center is a normal div with `margin`.